# Palindrome Checker in Mips

Tags: mips

I'm taking a computer organization class that teaches the low level functions of computers through MIPS Assembly. One problem on a homework is a palindrome checker. Here it is:

> Write a MIPS function (called “palindrome”) that returns 1 if the
>   input string is a palindrome and returns 0 otherwise. The address of
>   the string will be passed in $a0 and the value should be returned in
>   $v0. Here a string is a palindrome if it reads the same in forward or
>   backward direction (including white spaces, punctuation marks, and so
>   on, but is case insensitive (i.e., „A‟ and „a‟ are considered to be
>   the same)). Note the string is ended with „\0‟ (C/C++ convention). You
>   need to test your program using “test_palindrome.s”

I wrote a simple c++ program to solve the problem, including a basic tolower function. I then manually translated it to mips. I've gotten it to run, but checking the palindrome test strings with the my c++ program against the mips program, I don't get the same result.

To test the mips functions, I'm using a program the professor provided. It says none of them are palindromes. Here is the MIPS code, there is a commented section showing my original c++ code.

```
# Program to test if a palindrome function works properly or not
# Written by Xiuwen Liu for CDA 3100 - Homework #3, problem #2
# Register usage
# $s7 - save $ra
# $s2 - current address of the string to be tested
# $s3 - the next of the last string to be tested 
# $a0 - for function parameter / syscall parameter
# $v0 - syscall number / function return value

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    addu     $s7, $ra, $zero,   # Save the ra
    la  $s2,  test_str          # Load the starting address of the array
    la  $s3, is_pali_msg,       # the next of last address
pali_test_loop: 
    lw  $a0, 0($s2)             # $a0 is the address of the string
    li      $v0, 4              # system call to print a string
    syscall                     # print string
    li      $v0, 4              # print a new line
    la      $a0, newline
    li      $v0, 4 
    syscall
    lw  $a0, 0($s2)             # $a0 is the address of the string
    jal palindrome              # call palindrome
    beq $v0, $zero, pali_no     #if $v0 is 0, it is not a palindrome
    li      $v0, 4              #it is a palindrome
    la      $a0, is_pali_msg
    syscall
    j   pali_test_end
pali_no:                        #it is not a palindrome
    li      $v0, 4 
    la      $a0, not_pali_msg    
    syscall
pali_test_end:
    li      $v0, 4 
    la      $a0, newline
    syscall
    addiu   $s2, $s2, 4
    lw  $a0, 0($s2)
    beq $a0, $s3, pali_done
    j   pali_test_loop    

pali_done:
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
    addu    $ra, $zero, $s7     #restore $ra since the function calles
                                #another function
    jr      $ra
    add $zero, $zero, $zero
    add $zero, $zero, $zero
########## End of main function #########
```

So this is my code:

```
# My working c++ code
# int arrayLen ( char s[]) {
#    int counter = 0;
#    while(s[counter] != '\0'){
#        if (s[counter] > 64 && s[counter] < 91)
#            s[counter] = s[counter] + 32;
#        counter++;
#    }
#    return counter;
# }
#
# int palindrom(char s[]){
#    int i;
#    int l = arrayLen(s);
#    for(i=0;i<=l/2;i++)
#        if(s[i]!=s[l-i-1]) return 0;
#    return 1;
# }    

palindrome:
    addu    $s4, $ra, $zero     # save $ra
    jal arrayLen                # get string length and set to lowercase
    move    $t0, $zero          # i = 0
    move    $t1, $v1            # l = arrayLen(s)
    srl $t2, $t1, 1             # divide l by 2

palinFor:
    bgt $t0, $t2, palinForExit  # end for loop when i > l/2

    sub $t3, $t1, $t0           # l - i 
    addi    $t3, $t3, -1        # l - i - 1    

    add $t4, $a0, $t0           # s[i]
    add $t5, $a0, $t3           # s[l-i-1]
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1         # i++
    lbu $t4, ($t4)              # load s[i]
    lbu $t5, ($t5)              # load s[l-i-1]
    sne $t6, $t4, $t5           # if not equal, set $t6 to 1
    beq $t6, 1, palinForExit    # leave loop if not equal    

    j   palinFor                # loop again

palinForExit:
    sne     $v0, $t6, $zero     # set return value: 0 for not palindrome, 1 for palindrome
    addu    $ra, $zero, $s4     # restore $ra
    jr  $ra                     # return to function caller


arrayLen:
    li  $t0, 0                  # counter = 0
    sll $t1, $t0, 2             # counter * 4
    add $t1, $t1, $a0           # address of s[counter] in $t1
    lbu     $t2, ($t1)          # load s[counter]
while:
    beq $t2, 0, whileEnd        # skip to end of while loop if s[counter] == \0
    blt     $t2, 64, breakIf    # skip if not uppercase range
    bgt $t2, 91, breakIf        # skip if not uppercase range
    addi    $t2, $t2, 32        # add 32 to make character lowercase
    sw  $t2, ($t1)              # save change to memory
breakIf:
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1         # counter++
whileEnd:
    move    $v1, $t0            # return value of arrayLen is counter
    jr  $ra                     # return to function caller
```

And this is where my code stop and the .data section of the test code follows:

```
    .data
#The following examples were copied from 
#   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome
pali1:  
    .asciiz "Socorram me subi no on ibus em Marrocos" #Brazilian Portuguese
pali2:  
    .asciiz "Ein Neger mit Gazelle zagtim Regen nie" #German
pali3:  
    .asciiz "stressed  desserts"
pali4:
    .asciiz "palindromes"
pali5:  
    .asciiz "tattarrattat"
is_pali_msg: 
    .asciiz "    The string is a palindrome."
not_pali_msg: 
    .asciiz "    The string is not a palindrome."
newline:    
    .asciiz "\n"    
test_str:
    .word  pali1, pali2, pali3, pali4, pali5, is_pali_msg
```

My brain hurts from learning this stuff. Some direction to why it doesn't work would be appreciated, thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
.text

strlen:
    # ------------
    # arguments:
    # a0 = string
    # ------------

    li      $v0,    0                           #set return value to 0
strlen_loop:
    lb      $t0,    0($a0)                      #load byte from beginning of the string
    beq     $t0,    $0,     strlen_exit         #when character value is 0 we have 
                                                #reached the end of the string
    addi    $a0,    $a0,    1                   #shift pointer to string one space right
    addi    $v0,    $v0,    1                   #increment return value by one
    j       strlen_loop

strlen_exit:
    # ------------
    # returns:
    # INTEGER (string length)
    # ------------
    jr      $ra                                 #return

palindrom:
    # ------------
    # arguments:
    # a0 = string
    # ------------

    sub     $sp,    $sp,    8                   #allocate memory on stack
    sw      $ra     0($sp)                      #save return address
    sw      $a0     4($sp)                      #save argumrnt value

    jal     strlen                              #call strlen
    move    $t0,    $v0                         #save result

    lw      $a0     4($sp)                      #load argument
    move    $t1,    $a0                         #save its value to t1

    li      $t2,    1                           #set counter to 1
    li      $v0,    1                           #prepare return value
    div     $t3,    $t0,    2                   #calculate string length / 2
    addi    $t3,    $t3,    1                   #add one more in case of even number
palindrom_loop:
    bge     $t2,    $t3     palindrom_exit      #when counter reaches half of the string length - exit
    lb      $t4,    0($a0)                      #get character from beginning

    sub     $t5,    $t0,    $t2                 #subtract counter from the string length
    add     $t6,    $t5,    $t1                 #add index from the end of the string to start address
    lb      $t7,    0($t6)                      #get corresponding character from the end of the string

    beq     $t4,    $t7,    palindrom_continue  #check to determine are the characters exact match
    li      $v0,    0                           #if not return 0, immediately
    j       palindrom_exit

palindrom_continue:
    addi    $a0,    $a0,    1                   #shift pointer to string one space right
    addi    $t2,    $t2,    1                   #increment counter by one
    j       palindrom_loop

palindrom_exit:
    # ------------
    # returns:
    # TRUE (1) or FALSE (0)
    # ------------
    lw      $ra     0($sp)                      #load return address
    addi    $sp,    $sp,    8                   #free stack
    jr      $ra                                 #return

main:
    #entry point
    la      $a0,    str                         #load string
    jal     palindrom                           #call palindrom

    move    $a0,    $v0                         #set a0 to palindrom return value
    li      $v0,    1                           #set 1 to v0 - as this is system call for print int
    syscall                                     #make the call

    li      $v0,    10                          #set 10 to v0 - as this is system call for exit program
    syscall                                     #make the call

.data
    str: .asciiz "thiispalindrome_emordnilapsiiht"
```

The approach is to get character from beginning and the corresponding character from the end of the string. If they are exact match, continue execution by the time when counter reaches half of the string length. If any pair of characters are found different, stop execution immediately and return FALSE.

One more thing, I haven't implemented part where upper case letters are not different from the lower case letters. But it isn't hard. You can add it yourself. The idea is to test each loaded character if it's ascii is between A (65) and Z (90). If so you'll add 32 to ascii value and you'll get lower case letter.